# How do I change the expires_in value for an authentication token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, cloud, sap-cloud-platform, cloudfoundry-uaa

I tried following all the steps in the blog whose URL is mentioned below.

https://blogs.sap.com/2019/04/29/sap-cloud-platform-backend-service-tutorial-13-api-called-from-external-tool/

While I am getting the authentication token and the entire flow is running properly, I just cannot change the value of expires_in which is 43199 by default.

How do I change that to some other value, let's say 5 minutes (300 seconds) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include this in the UAA configuration in the xs-security.json or [manually update](https://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/update-service.html) the uaa using `cf update-service <uaa_instance_name> -c <json_file | inline-JSON object>`

```
"oauth2-configuration": {
      "token-validity": 7200
}
```

For fullness, here's a sample UAA JSON

```
{
  "xsappname": "example_uaa",
  "tenant-mode": "dedicated",
  "description": "Security profile of called application",
  "scopes": [
    {
      "name": "uaa.user",
      "description": "UAA"
    }
  ],
  "oauth2-configuration":{ 
      "token-validity": 7200
   },
  "role-templates": [
    {
      "name": "Token_Exchange",
      "description": "UAA",
      "scope-references": [
        "uaa.user"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```